# Is it true that Uzbek visas are regularly checked in the Tashkent Metro?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, officials, uzbekistan

I've read that local Police regularly checks foreigners' Uzbek visas in the Tashkent Metro.

Is this true? And what would happen if you didn't have you passport with you? Would you simply be refused entry to the Metro, or would the Police accompany you to the Hotel, or would they outright arrest you and call the hotel to verify one's immigration status?

Comment: You're probably referring ye regular document check....

Comment: Perhaps @MarkMayo could add his answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Local police regularly checks bags at the metro entry, but very rarely they will check visa.

If in such case you do not have a passport with you, no one will ask for bribe as @JonathanReez wrote, that's sounds very funny actually:)) they will verify your status and that is it, might call the hotel or take you to the hotel.

I lived in Tashkent for almost half of a year, used metro and never was asked for my visa, though I know people who very occasionally stopped and asked for documents, they had their documents with them (usually everyone carries their passport if travelling in foreign country), so they were fine.

Just keep you passport with you no matter which foreign country you visit:)

Comment: What's your ethnicity/outward appearance? It's quite typical in some countries for people who are obviously tourists to get way more hassle, whether from touts or the authorities, than do locals.

Comment: Do you speak Russian without an accent? That's a crucial variable in this question.

Comment: @davidvc I am originally from Germany.

Comment: @JonathanReez no, my Russian is not very good.

Comment: @AlexM I was never checked but I've figured it's because I look like a local and speak Russian. And I've heard plenty of stories about Westerners stopped at various points in the city. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: @AlexM So far I've never carried my passport on the street when staying in a City, even in countries like the US. I do have an official photo ID card (with the same info as in my passport, including nationality) which I always carry. Question is if that, together with the Hotel Registration Slips, would be enough to at least not be arrested

Comment: @JonathanReez when was that? actually I have heard from my local friends this had happened before, but changed.

Comment: @JonathanReez regarding deleting your answer, it is up to you, in my opinion it is "a bit" exaggerated:)

Comment: @Crazydre the official ID card will work fine, sorry for confusion, I meant to have with you any official ID card.